# Using PHP, how to send an encrypted file to a .NET script for decryption

Tags: php, .net, cookies

Here's the scenario:

Trying to implement a single sign on intranet system, but there are mixed PHP and .NET scripts, I am the PHP guy, but the cookie was created and encrypted by a .NET scripte, I can't figure out how to decrypt the cookie using PHP, so I'm going to send the encrypted cookie to the .NET script for decryption, and then the .NET script will send me back the data with JSON, all using a https secured connection. I am trying to figure out what's the best way to send the encrypted cookie over to the .NET script, can I just send the encrypted cookie as a string using "GET"?

Comment: not sure, I just took over the project, and was told the old decryption code in PHP no longer work. The code looked something like this:

$encryptedString64 = hex2bin($encrypted);

$keybytes = base64_decode($key64);
$ivbytes = base64_decode($iv64);

Comment: Here's the code in .net, can this be decrypted in PHP? : <machineKey validationKey="xxxxxx" decryptionKey="yyyyyy" validation="SHA1" decryption="3DES" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the encrypted cookie is a string and reasonably short, then just send it in a query string with GET. If it's binary data, then `base64_encode` it first. If the data is long, you'll probably want to do a POST instead.

You're probably better off, though, understanding how the .NET code decrypts things. Then you can write your own decryption in PHP.

Comment: Here's the code in .net, can this be decrypted in PHP? :
<machineKey  validationKey="xxxxxx" decryptionKey="yyyyyy" validation="SHA1" decryption="3DES" />

Comment: @KoKo: I don't know. I don't know if there's a SHA1 package for PHP. You might want to ask another question with this information.